# How to select the nearest date value in SQL using CASE WHEN expressions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date, case

Let's say I have two tables where I am attempting to compare date values. Basically, what I would like to do is write up a set of CASE WHEN expressions that will sift through two date columns (a regular date column and an assess date column) per each userID. In comparing these two date columns, I want to establish conditions where if a date value in the regular date column is not equal to the assess date value, select the nearest assess date value that comes prior to the regular date column. The second condition is if a regular date value and an assess date value are an equal number of days apart (for instance, if one assess date value is two days before the regular date value and another assess date value is two days after the regular date value, select the assess date value that comes before the regular date value).

It is set up like this currently:

```
SELECT t1.userID,

--if dates are equal, select the date that matches
CASE WHEN t1.ASSESS_DATE = t2.REG_DATE
THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ASSESS_DATE FROM DB_1.dbo.Table_A -- only want to return one record for each date value
      WHERE userID = t2.userID
      AND ASSESS_DATE = t2.REG_DATE
      ORDER BY REG_DATE ASC) -- not sure if this is needed

   --if ASSESS_DATE value is less than or greater than the REG_DATE
   --choose nearest ASSESS_DATE value that is before the REG_DATE
   ELSE CASE WHEN t1.ASSESS_DATE <= t2.REG_DATE OR t1.ASSESS_DATE >= t2.REG_DATE
   THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ASSESS_DATE FROM DB_1.dbo.Table_A
         WHERE userID = t2.userID
         AND ASSESS_DATE <= t2.REG_DATE
         ORDER BY ASSESS_DATE ASC)

         -- if two ASSESS_DATES are an equal number of days apart from the REG_DATE, 
         --choose the ASSESS_DATE value that comes before the REG_DATE
         ELSE CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, t2.REG_DATE, t1.ASSESS_DATE) = ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.ASSESS_DATE, t2.REG_DATE)) 
         THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ASSESS_DATE FROM DB_1.dbo.Table_A
               WHERE userID = t2.userID
               ORDER BY ASSESS_DATE ASC)
         END
    END
END AS ASSESS_DATE, t2.REG_DATE
FROM 
(SELECT userID, ASSESS_DATE 
 FROM DB_1.dbo.Table_A) t1 

INNER JOIN
(SELECT userID, REG_DATE
 FROM DB_2.dbo.Table_B) t2
 ON (t1.userID = t2.userID)
```

--Example tables

Table A:

```
 userID    ASSESS_DATE
---------|-------------
    1      2017-01-04
    2      2017-03-14
    3      2018-05-23
    4      2016-07-03
    4      2016-07-09
    5      2019-04-28
    6      2016-10-10
    7      2018-11-19
```

Table B:

```
 userID    REG_DATE
---------|-------------
    1      2017-01-04
    2      2017-03-14
    3      2018-05-28
    4      2016-07-06
    5      2019-05-03
    6      2016-10-04
    7      2018-12-05
```

As is shown above, *userID's 1* and *2* have equal ASSESS_DATE and REG_DATE values, so they can easily be matched. *userID 3* has an ASSESS_DATE value prior to the REG_DATE value. The ASSESS_DATE value should be paired with the REG_DATE value. *userID 4* has two ASSESS_DATE values, both of them being an equal number of days apart from the REG_DATE (three days before and three days after). I want to pair the ASSESS_DATE value that comes BEFORE the REG_DATE value. *userID 5* has an ASSESS_DATE value that comes prior to the REG_DATE value. *userID 6* has an ASSESS_DATE value that comes after the REG_DATE value. Since that is the only ASSESS_DATE value recorded for that userID, the query should select that ASSESS_DATE value. Finally, *userID 7* has an ASSESS_DATE value prior to the REG_DATE, so pair that date value with the REG_DATE value.

I would like the final table to look like this:

```
 userID   ASSESS_DATE    REG_DATE
--------|-------------|-------------|
   1      2017-01-04    2017-01-04 -- Values are equal
   2      2017-03-14    2017-03-14
   3      2018-05-23    2018-05-28 -- ASSESS_DATE is prior to REG_DATE
   4      2016-07-03    2016-07-06 -- Choose the ASSESS_DATE value that comes before REG_DATE
   5      2019-04-28    2019-05-03
   6      2016-10-10    2016-10-04
   7      2018-11-19    2018-12-05
```

That is the gist of it. I hope the query is easy to follow along with given the comments. Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and simplify the question.  It is very, very difficult for anyone to try to parse your query to figure out what it is doing and then try to understand your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I do have two example tables and a final table in my description. I can elaborate more if necessary. Are you able to see the example tables and final table in my description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation like this a window function can be your best friend.  The myriad of supported functions combined with a clever use of partitioning and ordering can give you the results you need without complex logic or a lengthy query.

In the example below a CTE is created that joins the two tables and then adds a couple of extra values that will be used in the window function.  These values are the date difference in days from *REG_DATE* to *ASSESS_DATE*, and the absolute value of the difference.  Then in the main query, the `FIRST_VALUE` function is used, partitioning all results by the userId, and REG_DATE, and sorting them by the absolute difference and then the normal difference.  The sort will guarantee that that the result will be the date with the lowest difference and when multiple results are equal, returning the one in the past.  Finally distinct is used because, unlike a regular aggregate, there will be one result for each result.

```
/** SETUP **/
DECLARE @Table_A TABLE ( [userID] int NOT NULL, [ASSESS_DATE] DATE NOT NULL );
DECLARE @Table_B TABLE ( [userID] int NOT NULL, [REG_DATE] DATE NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO @Table_A ( [userID],[ASSESS_DATE] )
VALUES (1, '2017-01-04'), (2, '2017-03-14'), (3, '2018-05-23'), (4, '2016-07-03'), (4, '2016-07-09'),   (5, '2019-04-28'),  (5, '2019-05-10'),  (6, '2016-10-10'),  (7, '2018-11-19');
INSERT INTO @Table_B ( [userID],[REG_DATE] )
VALUES (1, N'2017-01-04'), (2, N'2017-03-14'), (3, N'2018-05-28'), (4, N'2016-07-06'), (5, N'2019-05-03'), (6, N'2016-10-04'), (7, N'2018-12-05');

/** ANSWER **/
WITH src AS (
    SELECT b.*, a.ASSESS_DATE, diff, absDiff
    FROM @Table_B b
    INNER JOIN @Table_A a ON a.userID = b.userID
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, b.REG_DATE, a.ASSESS_DATE) diff) forDiff
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT ABS(forDiff.diff) absDiff) forAbsDiff
)
SELECT DISTINCT userID
    , FIRST_VALUE(ASSESS_DATE) OVER 
         (PARTITION BY userId, REG_DATE ORDER BY absDiff, diff) BestAssessDate, REG_DATE
FROM src
```